# get subfolders under a folder named with uppercases only

Tags: bash, path, find, filenames

I want to get the list of subfolders with names in uppercase only (folder name only, without leading `pardir` or tailing `/`).

I tried `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[A-Z]+'` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `-regex './[A-Z]+'` instead of `-name '[A-Z]+'`.

Comment: Using bash extended pattern matching operators (without `find`): `shopt -s extglob; dirs=(+([A-Z])/); printf '%s\n' "${dirs[@]%?}"`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns) operator does not use regular expressions as you might expect. Instead it using "wildcards" similar to the bash wildcard system as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Shell-Pattern-Matching).

You probably want to use the `-regex` operator as described in the [Full Name Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html) section of the documentation. Using this you should have a command like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[A-Z]+'
```

You can do any other path operations using the options described in the [Run Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Run-Commands) section.

Comment: Thanks, but why `find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '[A-Z]+'` doesn't work? I can use `find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[A-Z]+' | cut -d'/' -f2` to remove the leading `./`, but it cannot be generalized to an arbitrary path rather than `./`.

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot to add the link. The `-regex` falls under a group of operators that look at the full path of a file rather than the basename so you have to account for the parent directory in the regex pattern as well. See the docs under [Full Name Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want upper-case names in Regex, use the `[:upper:]` class name:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex './[[:upper:]]+'
```

Or using Bash's `extglob` Extended Globbing:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
printf %s\\n +([[:upper:]])/
```